# Using Gulp to create an SVG sprite without compression

Tags: svg, gulp, sprite

I'm attempting to use [this](https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite/) plugin on every SVG in a given project.

I believe the default compression or reformatting of the svg's themselves is causing issues however.

For example, I have a standard three bar menu icon:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <svg width="200px" height="180px" viewBox="0 0 200 180" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <g id="Artboard-1" fill="#D8D8D8"> <rect id="Rectangle-1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="40"></rect> <rect id="Rectangle-1" x="0" y="70" width="200" height="40"></rect> <rect id="Rectangle-1" x="0" y="140" width="200" height="40"></rect> </g> </g> </svg>
```

But once it's compressed:

```
<symbol id="menu" viewBox="0 0 200 180"> <g fill="#D8D8D8" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 0h200v40H0zM0 70h200v40H0zM0 140h200v40H0z"/></g> </symbol>
```

Making it impossible for me to do any animation to the different rect items that I could do with it before it was moved into the sprite.

Is there any way to turn off the compression or reformatting?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite) it should be possible to remove svgo from the transformation process via

```
{
    shape : {
        transform           : []
    }
}
```