# gulp imagemin breaking SVG mask

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp, imagemin

I have an SVG file like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="gradient" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop stop-offset="0" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I'm using gulp-imagemin to compress all my images including SVGs. The specific task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('/src/img/**/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/img'));
});
```

Works great for most of my images. However for the SVG file above, the output is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a" x2="0" y2="1"><stop stop-color="transparent"/><stop stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)" offset="1"/></linearGradient></defs></svg>
```

Notice the `mask` has been removed (which is essential) and the id changed. Is there a way to stop this happening, or even to disable SVG compression with this plugin? I've looked at the documentation and can't see a way.

Comment: @RobertLongson No, don't think that has anything useful in I'm afraid

Comment: How about this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023039/using-gulp-to-create-an-svg-sprite-without-compression/38036872#38036872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/img/**/*.*')
   .pipe(imagemin([
     imagemin.svgo({
       plugins: [ 
         { removeUselessDefs: false },
         { cleanupIDs: false} 
       ]
     }),
     imagemin.gifsicle(),
     imagemin.jpegtran(),
     imagemin.optipng()
   ]).on('error', gutil.log))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});
```

This was the resulting SVG that it produced:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="gradient" x2="0" y2="1"><stop stop-color="transparent"/><stop stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)" offset="1"/></linearGradient><mask id="mask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"><path fill="url(#gradient)" d="M0 0h1v1H0z"/></mask></defs></svg>
```

I basically just disabled two options for the `imagemin.svgo()` plugin:

- Disabling `removeUselessDefs` preserved the `<mask>`
- Disabling `cleanupIDs` preserved the `id` attributes

If for some reason this doesn't work for you or there are other optimizations that are causing you problems, there's [a whole list of options](https://github.com/svg/svgo#what-it-can-do) that you can enable and disable. Just try them until you find the ones that fit your use case.

If everything else fails, just remove the entire `imagemin.svgo()` call from the array that is passed to `imagemin()`. That way only `.gif`, `.jpg` and `.png` files will be minimized.

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thanks